# Create a List from fields in a pandas dataframe using list comprehension

Tags: pandas, list-comprehension, python-3.6

Hello I am struggling to create a list object from the following DF:

```
   In [102]: trd 
    Out[102]: 
        side    chg
    EWJ  BUY  100.0
    IEV  BUY   70.0
    VGK  SELL  30.0
```

Desired output:

```
[MarketOrder('BUY',100), MarketOrder('BUY',70), MarketOrder('SELL',30)]
```

tried the following without success.

```
orders = [MarketOrder(str(trd['side']), trd['chg']) for rows in trd.index]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `MarketOrder` a function, or do you want the literal string `"MarketOrder"`?

Comment: Its a function actually

Comment: In that case, jezrael has the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
orders = [MarketOrder(x[0], x[1]) for x in zip(trd['side'], trd['chg'])]
```

Or:

```
orders = [MarketOrder(x, y) for x,y in zip(trd['side'], trd['chg'])]
```

In your list comprehension in each loop create use `MarketOrder` with columns `side`, `chg` `len(trd.index)` times.